# The Improper Integral and Continuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, improper-integrals

My Laplace transform textbook's definition of improper integral is

> The improper integral is defined in the obvious way by taking the limit:
>
> $\lim\limits_{R \to \infty} \int\limits_a^R F(x) \ dx = \int\limits^\infty_a F(x) \ dx$
>
> provided $F(x)$ is continuous in the interval $a \le x \le R$ for every $R$, and the limit on the left exists.

Shouldn't the condition be that $F(x)$ has at most finitely many jump discontinuities (that is, that $F(x)$ is piecewise continuous), as is the requirement for Riemann integrability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Riemann integrability is a weaker condition than continuity on a closed interval [a, R] so the definition is just a little stronger than required.

Comment: So it would be more accurate to say "piecewise continuous" in the definition rather than just "continuous"?

Comment: Both are accurate, it's a question of how weak you want your definitions and theorems to be. It's good that you've identified when something can be a little weaker.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help. I will accept answer when timer allows.

Comment: Well, for the most loose definition, you can use Lebesgue criterion of Rieemen Integrability. It states f is Riemann integrable if and only if the set of discontinuities has measure 0